# How to remove vue non-props component instance?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

Can we remove/delete non-props component instance that accidentally rendered by Vue?
I've tried to using `inheritAttrs: false` (but yeah not included to component props and emits properties), or `deleteThisComponent(idx{this.idx.splice(this.idx.indexOf(idx, 1))}` but it didn't work.

I need to remove them because it should'nt be there, in my case it should be only component instance with props that rendered. See Vue component inspect below.

[image]

P.S I want to remove 4 and 5, they didnt have any props. Even I didn't set any value on data property for index 4 and 5.

Here are my non-working code,
on MyTab.html its more like the skeleton

```
<div class="tab__header">
      <a
        v-for="(tab, idx) in tabs"
        v-bind="$attrs"
        :class="class(idx)"
        :key="idx"
        tabindex="0">
        <span class="tab__icon" v-if="hasIcon">
          <component :is="tabTitle.icon" />
        </span>
        {{ tabTitle.title}}
      </a>
    </div>
```

And on the Tab.js as the base js.

```
export default {
  inheritAttrs: false,
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.tabs = this.$children //I also wonder, is the problem is from here or not? Since normal Javascript patterns here used to get all of the children.
  }
//....
}
```

And here are the tab.js to include the template and data property,

```
//....
myTabTemplate: `
 <div>
   <MyTab>
     <TabHeader
       v-for="(tab, idx) in tabs"
       :key="idx"
       :title="tab.title"
       :icon="tab.icon">
       <h3>Heading {{idx + 1}}</h3> {{ tab.title}}
      </TabHeader>
   </MyTab>
 </div>
`,
myTabScript: {
 data () {
   return {
     items: [
      {
       icon: `User`,
       title:'First Tab'
      },
      {
       icon: `Wishlist`,
       title:'Second Tab'
      },
      {
       title:'Third Tab'
      }, 
      {
       title:'Fourth Tab'
      }
     ]
   }
 }
},
```

Comment: what is a `vue non-props component instance`?
You mean dumb components that only render and dont contain any props?

Comment: @flx It's non props attribute. "A component non-prop attribute is an attribute or event listener that is passed to a component, but does not have a corresponding property defined in props or emits. " - https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#attribute-inheritance

Comment: ah okay.
can you show your non-working code (or similar example) using inheritAttrs: false?

Comment: Sure @flx, edited on the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a filter condition before your assign to v-for's resource.

*for your example:*

tab.js

```
  created() {
    this.tabs = this.$children.filter(child => {
        const hasProps = !!child.$options.props;
        return hasProps;
    })
  }
```

Comment: Ohh it works perfectly! But not in created(), thank you so much @Chunbin Li

Comment: it depends on when you want to filter, you can move the filter logic to any method or hook by your feature. the key point is you have to filter v-for data and reassign it.